# How to check user credential for login into the app with SQFLite in flutter

Tags: flutter, dynamic, future, sqflite

I try to check the username and password that saved into the table before in register page. and if username and password have existed into the table then handle user navigation and navigate to some another screen user.

but when I try to access the table and check the username and password with this method:

```
  Future<dynamic> checkLogin(String userName, String password) async {
    final dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.query(USER_TABLE,
        where: "$USERNAME = ?  AND $PASSWORD = ?",
        whereArgs: [userName, password],
        limit: 1);
  }
```

I got this error:
`Another exception was thrown: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

may please guide me on how I must change this method to get username and password and then according to the result handle user navigation? 
thanks for your help.

edit:

login_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:atlas_gen_demo/screens/register_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:atlas_gen_demo/Animation/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'package:flushbar/flushbar.dart';
import 'package:atlas_gen_demo/data/storage/db_helper.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/login';

  var dbHelper;

  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void navigateToRegister(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
      RegisterScreen.routeName,
    );
  }

  validate(BuildContext ctx) {
    if (usernameController.text != "" && passwordController.text != "") {
      dbHelper = DBHelper();

      var test =
          dbHelper.checkLogin(usernameController.text, passwordController.text);
      // just for test what we got here
      showFlushBar(ctx, "test", test);
      //navigateToUsersList(ctx);
    } else {
      showFlushBar(ctx, "خطا", "اطلاعات را وارد نمایید");
    }
  }

  void navigateToUsersList(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
      LoginScreen.routeName,
    );
  }

  void showFlushBar(BuildContext context, String title, String text) {
    Flushbar(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      borderRadius: 8,
      backgroundGradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [Colors.purple.shade800, Colors.purpleAccent.shade700],
        stops: [0.6, 1],
      ),
      boxShadows: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black,
          offset: Offset(3, 3),
          blurRadius: 3,
        )
      ],
      dismissDirection: FlushbarDismissDirection.HORIZONTAL,
      forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
      titleText: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'mainBold', color: Colors.white),
      ),
      messageText: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'mainMedium', color: Colors.white),
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    ).show(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 250,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/login.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: FadeAnimation(
                    1.8,
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "ورود به برنامه",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, 1),
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontFamily: 'persianBold',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                              blurRadius: 20.0,
                              offset: Offset(0, 10))
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]),
                            )),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: usernameController,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: "نام کاربری",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  fontFamily: 'persianMedium',
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: passwordController,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: "کلمه عبور",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  fontFamily: 'persianMedium',
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    FadeAnimation(
                        2,
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () => validate(context),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [
                                  Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .4),
                                  Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .8),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "ورود به برنامه",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: 'persianBold',
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    FadeAnimation(
                        1.5,
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () => navigateToRegister(context),
                          child: Text(
                            "ثبت نام در برنامه",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'persianMedium',
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .6),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

db_helper.dart:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import '../../models/user.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Database _db;
  static const String ID = 'id';
  static const String NAME = 'name';
  static const String FAMILY = 'family';
  static const String USERNAME = 'username';
  static const String PASSWORD = 'password';
  static const String BIRTHDAY = 'birthday';
  static const String MOBILE = 'mobile';
  static const String NATIONAL_ID = 'nationalId';
  static const String USER_TABLE = 'User';
  static const String DB_NAME = 'user.db';

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }

    _db = await initDb();

    return _db;
  }

  initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, DB_NAME);
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE $USER_TABLE ($ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $NAME TEXT, $FAMILY TEXT, $USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL, $PASSWORD TEXT , $BIRTHDAY TEXT, $MOBILE TEXT, $NATIONAL_ID TEXT UNIQUE)");
  }

  Future<User> save(User user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    user.id = await dbClient.insert(USER_TABLE, user.toMap());
    return user;
  }

  Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query(USER_TABLE, columns: [
      ID,
      NAME,
      FAMILY,
      USERNAME,
      PASSWORD,
      BIRTHDAY,
      MOBILE,
      NATIONAL_ID
    ]);

    List<User> users = [];

    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        users.add(User.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return users;
  }

  Future<dynamic> getUser(String nationalId) async {
    final dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.query(USER_TABLE,
        where: "$NATIONAL_ID = ?", whereArgs: [nationalId], limit: 1);
  }

  Future<User> checkLogin(String userName, String password) async {
    final dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM $USER_TABLE WHERE username = '$userName' and password = '$password'");

    if (res.length > 0) {
      return new User.fromMap(res.first);
    }

    return null;
  }

  Future<int> delete(String nationalId) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient
        .delete(USER_TABLE, where: '$nationalId = ?', whereArgs: [nationalId]);
  }

  Future<int> update(User user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.update(USER_TABLE, user.toMap(),
        where: '$NATIONAL_ID = ?', whereArgs: [user.nationalId]);
  }

  Future close() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code that you use to call this method

Comment: login_screen and db_helper class added - jideguru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkLogin` is a Future so you'll need to await it like this in your `validate`

```
   validate(BuildContext ctx) async {
        if (usernameController.text != "" && passwordController.text != "") {
          dbHelper = DBHelper();

          User test =
              await dbHelper.checkLogin(usernameController.text, passwordController.text);
          // just for test what we got here
          showFlushBar(ctx, "test", test.toString());
          //navigateToUsersList(ctx);
        } else {
          showFlushBar(ctx, "خطا", "اطلاعات را وارد نمایید");
        }
      }
```

Comment: I got this error after change validation method: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'User' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (27590): #0      LoginScreen.validate (package:atlas_gen_demo/screens/login_screen.dart:28:33)`

Comment: thank you for your help. it's work now. that code I wrote for DB handler is ok? and if I want to use DB handler method in another screen I had to implement like that you did here?